# Regex to find hashtag in string - without taking the initial hashtag symbol

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to do this in PHP and I am just wondering as I'm not great with Regex.

I'm trying to find all hashtags in a string, and wrap them in a link to twitter. In order to do this I need the content of the hashtag, without the symbol.

I want to select the `#hashtag` - without the preceding `#` => Just to return `hashtag`?

I'd like to do it in one line but I'm doing a `preg_replace`, followed by a string replace as shown:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\B#([a-z0-9_-]+)/i', '<a 
href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/$0" target="_blank">$0</a> ', $string);
    $string = str_replace('https://twitter.com/hashtag/#', 'https://twitter.com/hashtag/', $string);
```

Any guidance is apprecaited!

Comment: @chris85 I still wanted the value with the # in it also - so it can appear in the anchor text as `<a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/myHashTag">#myHashTag</a>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was using a regex tester and found the answer.

`preg_replace` was returning two values, one `$0` with the `#hashtag` value, and `$1` with the `hashtag` value - without the # symbol.

Tested here (select preg_replace): http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/kOn

Perhaps it is something to do with the regex itself I'm not sure. Hopefully this helps someone else too.

My one liner is:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\B#([a-z0-9_-]+)/i', '<a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/$1" target="_blank">$0</a> ', $string);
```

Edit: I understand it now. The added brackets `( )` around the square brackets effectively return the `$1` variable. Otherwise the whole pattern is `$0`.

Comment: Well done, I'm upvoting you for finding the answer yourself :-) `$0` returns the portion of the string that matches the entire expression, where `$1` matches the first matched group (what's between the first `(` and `)`). If you had a second set of `(` and `)`, that second group would be in `$2`.